# I'm having an issue with the calculator that I'm building on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

I currently have all of the buttons needed. However, the Operators button is not using the character. At the time that you click in one of the operators is not returning anything.

```
package com.example.mycalculator

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var lastNumeric : Boolean = false
    var lastDot : Boolean = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }

    fun onDigit(view: View){

        tvInput.append((view as Button).text)
        lastNumeric = true
    }

    fun onClear(view: View){

        tvInput.text = ""
        lastNumeric = false
        lastDot = false


    }

    fun onDecimalPoint(view: View){
        if (lastNumeric && !lastDot){
            tvInput.append(".")
            lastNumeric = false
            lastDot = false
        }
    }


    fun onEqual(view: View){
        if(lastNumeric){
            var tvValue = tvInput.text.toString()
             var prefix = "="

            try {
                    if(tvValue.contains("-")){
                        val splitValue = tvValue.split("-")
                        var one = splitValue[0]
                        var two = splitValue[1]

                        if(!prefix.isEmpty()){
                            one = prefix + one
                        }
                    // Check if it is empty or if we have a second minus
                            tvInput.text = (one.toDouble() - two.toDouble()).toString()

                }  else if(tvValue.contains("/")){
                    val splitValue = tvValue.split("/")
                    var one = splitValue[0]
                    var two = splitValue[1]
                    // Check if it is empty or if we have a second minus
                    if(!prefix.isEmpty()){
                        one = prefix + one
                    }

                    tvInput.text = (one.toDouble() / two.toDouble()).toString()

                }else if(tvValue.contains("*")){
                    val splitValue = tvValue.split("*")
                    var one = splitValue[0]
                    var two = splitValue[1]
                    // Check if it is empty or if we have a second minus
                    if(!prefix.isEmpty()){
                        one = prefix + one
                    }
                    tvInput.text = (one.toDouble() * two.toDouble()).toString()

                }else if(tvValue.contains("+")){
                    val splitValue = tvValue.split("+")
                    var one = splitValue[0]
                    var two = splitValue[1]
                    // Check if it is empty or if we have a second minus
                    if(!prefix.isEmpty()){
                        one = prefix + one
                    }


                    tvInput.text = (one.toDouble() + two.toDouble()).toString()
                }
            }catch (e: ArithmeticException){
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }



    fun onOperator(view: View){
        if(lastNumeric && !isOperatorAdded(tvInput.toString())){
            tvInput.append((view as Button).text)
            lastNumeric = false
        }
    }

    private fun isOperatorAdded(value: String) : Boolean {
        return if (value.startsWith("-")){
           false
        } else  value.contains("/") || value.contains("*") || value.contains("+") || value.contains("-")
    }
}
```

Inside of the activity_main, I have that the operator is coming through onClick element call "onOperator."

Example:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:width="0dp"
            android:text="+"
            android:onClick="onOperator"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            />
```

Does anyone know what is the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean it is not returning anything? 

1. Does the code flow call the `onOperator` method?
2. Does your `If` condition succeed?
3. Did you add a breakpoint and check what is the value of `view` within the scope?

Comment: I'm able to click every number as much as I can see the numbers, but everything else is not visible. The following operators are not visible (+, -, *, /)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is `tvInput`? you haven't declared it anywhere, but using in many places... (stripped out code?)

looks like `tvInput` is a `TextView`, you are using `tvInput.text.toString()` in one of your lines

so your `if` condition in `onOperator` is wrong

```
if(lastNumeric && !isOperatorAdded(tvInput.toString())){
```

you should check text placed in `tvInput`, not `tvInput` itself (as `View`). `tvInput.toString()` will return some "random" `String` representing this `View`, not content of this `View`. try with this line:

```
if(lastNumeric && !isOperatorAdded(tvInput.text.toString())){
```

and get familiar with [logging](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat), its crucial... you could put a `Log` line in `onOperator` and find out by yourself that these conditions/values are wrong

Comment: Thanks, the issue has been solved with your help